# data i entered in the admin page not reflecting in my webpage,

Tags: django-templates

The data i entered in the admin page not showing up on the web page.
i don't know what is going wrong with my code, please help
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2B2A.png)

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

# Register your models here.

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','slug','status','created_on')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ['title','content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('blogspot/',views.PostList.as_view(), name="b"),
    path('<slug:slug>/',views.PostDetail.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

Comment: Please post related html templates

Comment: There is no files added